Publish javadoc with gradle on github package
I have a gradle project which is used as an API. This API is published on github package, but without javadoc, even if the comment are well present on github's repository.
The main build.gradle is like that:
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id "maven-publish"
    id 'io.github.goooler.shadow' version '8.1.7'
}

java.toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "github"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/MyProject/MyProject")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials);
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        gpr(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("build/libs/MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar") {
               builtBy shadowJar
            }
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'myproject'
        }
    }
}

archivesBaseName = 'MyProject'

sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src']
    resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName.set('MyProject')
    archiveClassifier.set(null)
}

build.dependsOn shadowJar

When using ./gradlew shadowJar publish it works fine, and I well see the package available on github. I can access to it, but there is only the jar file, without source AND without the javadoc. So my IDE doesn't show me comment when using method, even if they have.
To be clear, when using this code:
public class Test {
   /**
    * Run all tests.
    */
   public static void runTests() {
   }
}

I don't see the Run all tests comment when using code Test.runTests(). (Even if I do for some others dependencies, so the issue is not from my IDE)
I tried to add this:
java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

But I got error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishGprPublicationToGithubRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'gpr' to repository 'github'
   > Could not PUT 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/MyProject/MyProject/com/example/myproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myproject-1.0-20240906.132919-68.jar.sha1'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict

I'm using this github action to publish it:
name: Build with gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        distribution: 'temurin'
        java-version: '21'
        cache: gradle
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build
      run: ./gradlew shadowJar publish -PgithubAuthHeaderName='Authorization' -PgithubAuthHeaderValue='Bearer ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}'
    - name: Upload Artifact to GitHub Action
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with: 
        name: MyProject
        path: build/libs/MyProject-*.jar

How can I publish javadoc to github package with gradle?
I made a MCVE :

Github repository GradlePublishIssue that is an example of API. Simply contains com.elikill58.test.GradleIssue class, with method checkIfIssue that has comment.
Github repository GradlePublishIssueExample that use the first example.
In case of eclipse, here is what I see:


Note: Both github actions use TOKEN as secret, which a basic auth token. Else, you can change according to your way of auth.

Please provide a MCVE as a public repo. That'd be helpful to debug this. Thanks!

@Azeem here is done: I just edit the post with 2 github repository for the example. Both are public and ready to use :)

@Azeem did you find something helpful?

Not yet. I'll look into it thoroughly over the weekend and update you.

@Azeem Ok, don't forget the bounty will expire in 2 days ^^

Add task to generate Javadocs in build.gradle:
task generateJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/docs/javadoc")
}

modify publishing block:
publishing {
    publications {
        gpr(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("build/libs/MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar") {
                builtBy shadowJar
            }
            artifact tasks.generateJavadoc {
                classifier "javadoc"
            }
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'myproject'
        }
    }
}

Also to make sure docs are generating:
publish.dependsOn generateJavadoc

after adding all these 3 parts you should be able to publish docs.

The doc say since gradle 8, we should use archiveClassifier. But even with (or without) the change, I got Could not find method archiveClassifier() for arguments [javadoc] on task ':generateJavadoc' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc. error. Build result

Even with classifier it doesn't works. I tried changing the plugin "java-library" to "java" but it didn't changed anything. To be sure your solution is working, check for github example I gave at end of my question
